# MariaDB: Creating view across schemas? How to handle permissions? Can someone explain this with a little example?

Tags: mariadb, database-administration

Please explain this only in the context of MariaDB.

-> Creating view across schemas?
-> How to handle permissions?
-> Would like to know if it is possible to grant permission to only a single view to some DBUser where that user must NOT be having permissions to any other DB object in that schema....!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to set permissions that require that the user NOT have some other permissions.

Comment: Please don't tag your question MySQL if you specifically want the answer to be only about MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can `grant` a privilege on a view and it is considered and not the underlying privileges on the underlying tables:

```
MariaDB [test]> create user bob;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]> grant select on test.v to bob;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]> show create view v\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                View: v
         Create View: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dan`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `v` AS select `mysql`.`global_priv`.`Host` AS `Host`,`mysql`.`global_priv`.`User` AS `User`,`mysql`.`global_priv`.`Priv` AS `Priv` from `mysql`.`global_priv`
character_set_client: latin1
collation_connection: latin1_swedish_ci
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Connecting as the `bob` user:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from mysql.global_priv;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table `mysql`.`global_priv`

MariaDB [(none)]> select * from test.v\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Host: localhost
User: mariadb.sys
Priv: {"access":0,"plugin":"mysql_native_password","authentication_string":"","account_locked":true,"password_last_changed":0}
*************************** 2. row ***************************
Host: localhost
User: root
Priv: {"access":18446744073709551615,"plugin":"mysql_native_password","authentication_string":"invalid","auth_or":[{},{"plugin":"unix_socket"}]}
...
```

As @Barmar said, giving a view access where there was access to the underlying table isn't possible (without making some tricky privilege based criteria part of the view where it returns 0 rows if the user has access to underlying table). But I suspect this might have been bad wording in your question.